# How to Synchronize the file writes in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

I am using the EJS compile  to create notification templates and I would like to know how to write the file to the file system in parallel and send the notification once all the files are saved.

Please see the below code snippet which I used

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var arrayOfData = [someData]; //Prepare data from database

//Iterate through the data
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfData.length; i++) {
   generateFileFromTemplate(arrayOfData[i],function(){});
}

function generateFileFromTemplate(templateData,callback)
{
   var outputFile = fileData.Id + ".html";
   var compiled = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync('email-template.ejs', 'utf8'));
   var html = compiled(templateData);

   fs.writeFile(outputFile, html, callback);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) for your use case

```
async.each(arrayOfData, 
  function(ele, next){
    generateFileFromTemplate(ele,function(){});
  }, 
  function(err){
    if(err) console.log('err', err);
    sendNotification();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a great utility library called Async, particularly its `parallel` method: https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel.
Here's an example:

```
var async = require('async');
/*-------------*/
var tasks = arrayOfData.map(function(data) {
    return function(cb) {
        generateFileFromTemplate(data,function(){});
        cb(null);
    }
});

async.parallel(tasks, function(err) {
    console.log('My job is done');
})
```

Comment: Can you accept either of the answers as a solution please?